# What is the working directory of embedded tomcat server tomcat-embed-core?

Tags: spring, eclipse, server, directory

I have a spring project imported into eclipse, I can't find the built-in server working directory. I tried searching in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 but there is not org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0, there are many others folders but they have different names and none of them have tmp0.Can anyone help me please?
I necessarily have to clean the server because it runs old files, while debugging I noticed that the content of the jsp files does not correspond to the current one.
Thank you.
[image: directory]
[image: directory2]

pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    
   
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 <!--  <version>5.3.23</version> -->
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-55</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  <!--  <version>9.0.40</version> -->
 </dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
 <!--  <version>6.0.0</version> -->
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
<artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
 <!--  <version>3.1.0.M3</version> -->
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<!--   <version>4.0.1</version>-->
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <!--  <version>2.7.5</version> -->
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
 <!--   <version>9.0.65</version> -->
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

STACKTRACE:

```
 18:19:11.963 [Thread-0] DEBUG 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloa
der.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader 
org.springframework.boot.dev
tools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@5eeb49de

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

2022-11-15 18:19:13.947  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.giuggiola.Parlament
oApplication      : Starting ParlamentoApplication using Java 
18.0.2.1 on UTENTE
-4KLNCD55 with PID 5968 (C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\BACKUP 
pARLAMENTO\Parlament
o\target\classes started by segreteria in 
C:\Users\segreteria\Desktop\BACKUP pAR
LAMENTO\Parlamento)
2022-11-15 18:19:13.957  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.giuggiola.Parlament
oApplication      : The following 1 profile is active: 
"@spring.profiles.active@
"
2022-11-15 18:19:14.353  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.e.DevToolsPropertyDefa
ultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 
'spring.devtools.add-
properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-11-15 18:19:14.354  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.e.DevToolsPropertyDefa
ultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider 
setting the 'log
ging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-11-15 18:19:18.727  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, 
entering strict reposito
ry configuration mode
2022-11-15 18:19:18.742  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Elasticsearch 
repositories in DEFA
ULT mode.
2022-11-15 18:19:19.263  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not 
safely identify store 
assignment for repository candidate interface 
com.giuggiola.repository.Parlament
areRepository; If you want this repository to be a 
Elasticsearch repository, con
sider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: 
org.springframewor
k.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or 
consider extending one
 of the following types with your repository: 
org.springframework.data.elasticse
arch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository, 
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.
repository.ElasticsearchRepository
2022-11-15 18:19:19.273  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
 .RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Elasticsearch - Could not 
safely identify store 
assignment for repository candidate interface 
com.giuggiola.repository.RangeRepo
sitory; If you want this repository to be a Elasticsearch 
repository, consider a
nnotating your entities with one of these annotations: 
org.springframework.data.
elasticsearch.annotations.Document (preferred), or consider 
extending one of the
 following types with your repository: 
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.re
pository.ElasticsearchRepository, 
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.reposit
ory.ElasticsearchRepository
2022-11-15 18:19:19.275  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 
505 ms. Found 0 
Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
2022-11-15 18:19:19.296  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, 
entering strict reposito
ry configuration mode
2022-11-15 18:19:19.299  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive 
Elasticsearch repositorie
s in DEFAULT mode.
2022-11-15 18:19:19.306  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch - Could 
not safely identi
fy store assignment for repository candidate interface 
com.giuggiola.repository.
ParlamentareRepository; If you want this repository to be a 
Reactive Elasticsear
ch repository, consider annotating your entities with one of 
these annotations: 
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document 
(preferred), or cons
ider extending one of the following types with your repository: 
org.springframew
ork.data.elasticsearch.repository.
ReactiveElasticsearchRepository
2022-11-15 18:19:19.309  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.RepositoryConfiguratio
nExtensionSupport : Spring Data Reactive Elasticsearch - Could 
not safely identi
fy store assignment for repository candidate interface 
com.giuggiola.repository.
RangeRepository; If you want this repository to be a Reactive 
Elasticsearch repo
sitory, consider annotating your entities with one of these 
annotations: org.spr
ingframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document 
(preferred), or consider ex
tending one of the following types with your repository: 
org.springframework.dat
a.elasticsearch.repository.ReactiveElasticsearchRepository
2022-11-15 18:19:19.309  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 
10 ms. Found 0 R
eactive Elasticsearch repository interfaces.
2022-11-15 18:19:19.383  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, 
entering strict reposito
ry configuration mode
2022-11-15 18:19:19.408  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories 
in DEFAULT mode.
2022-11-15 18:19:19.576  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConf
igurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 
142 ms. Found 2 
JPA repository interfaces.
2022-11-15 18:19:22.420  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat
.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 
(http)
2022-11-15 18:19:22.501  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.apache.catalina.core.
StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-11-15 18:19:22.517  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.apache.catalina.core
Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-11-15 18:19:24.171  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.apache.jasper.servl
et.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet 
contained no TLDs.
 Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of 
JARs that were scan
ned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs 
during scanning can i
mprove startup time and JSP compilation time.
2022-11-15 18:19:24.258  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[loc
alhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded 
WebApplicationContext
2022-11-15 18:19:24.259  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
w.s.c.ServletWebServerA
pplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization 
completed in 9900
 ms
2022-11-15 18:19:25.172  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.hibernate.jpa.interna
l.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo 
[name: default]
2022-11-15 18:19:25.452  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.hibernate.Version  
                  : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 
5.6.11.Final
2022-11-15 18:19:26.087  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.hibernate.annotations
.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations 
{5.1.2.Final}
2022-11-15 18:19:26.575  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.Hikar
iDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-11-15 18:19:27.320  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.Hikar
iDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-11-15 18:19:27.395  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.hibernate.dialect.D
ialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10
Dialect
2022-11-15 18:19:29.015  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
Hibernate Types        
                  : This framework is proudly powered by:

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
 _    _                           _     _
| |  | |                         (_)   | |
| |__| |_   _ _ __   ___ _ __ ___ _ ___| |_ ___ _ __   ___ ___
|  __  | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '__/ __| / __| __/ _ \ '_ \ / __/ _ \
| |  | | |_| | |_) |  __/ |  \__ \ \__ \ ||  __/ | | | (_|  __/
|_|  |_|\__, | .__/ \___|_|  |___/_|___/\__\___|_| |_|\___\___|
         __/ | |
        |___/|_|

At Hypersistence, we only build amazing tools, like Hibernate 
Types, Flexy Pool,
 or Hypersistence Optimizer.

What if there were a tool that could automatically detect JPA 
and Hibernate perf
ormance issues?

Hypersistence Optimizer is that tool! For more details, go to: 

https://vladmihalcea.com/hypersistence-optimizer/


<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

2022-11-15 18:19:30.798  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatfo
rmInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform 
implementation: [org.hibernate.
engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-11-15 18:19:30.841  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
j.LocalContainerEntityM
anagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for 
persistence unit 'd
efault'
2022-11-15 18:19:32.461  WARN 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
JpaBaseConfiguration$Jp
 aWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by 
default. Therefore, da
tabase queries may be performed during view rendering. 
Explicitly configure spri
ng.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-11-15 18:19:33.031 DEBUG 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 
0 @InitBinder, 1 
RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2022-11-15 18:19:33.265 DEBUG 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMapp
ingHandlerMapping : 13 mappings in 
'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2022-11-15 18:19:33.363 DEBUG 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleU
rlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 
'resourceHandlerMapping'
2022-11-15 18:19:33.427 DEBUG 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
.m.m.a.ExceptionHandler
ExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 
@ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyA
dvice
2022-11-15 18:19:35.760  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveR
eloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-11-15 18:19:35.908  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat
.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with 
context path ''
2022-11-15 18:19:35.960  INFO 5968 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.giuggiola.Parlament
oApplication      : Started ParlamentoApplication in 23.955 
seconds (JVM running
 for 26.681)
```

structure:
[image: structure]
[image: structure]

Comment: The embedded server of what? Spring Boot, the one from Eclipse (that isn't really an embedded one just a regular Tomcat).

Comment: spring boot i believe because i have three jar files: tomcat-emded-core , tomcat-embed-el, tomcat-embed-websocket

Comment: That doesn't use a directory, that is the whole point of an embedded server.

Comment: You're asking for details on a presumptive solution to a problem you haven't actually explained. If this were a normal Tomcat server launched by Eclipse, you'd right-click on it in the Servers View and Clean the working directory from there. Maybe you should back up and explain the actual problem so you can get the correct solution for it.

Comment: ok i put the pom, the stacktrace and the structure

Comment: since it doesn't run a jsp page for me, I noticed in debug that the lines of code don't match with the current file, so I wanted to clean the folder

Comment: my project doesn't show me a jsp page, I didn't want to switch to the external server, because there I have other errors and it doesn't show me the other two pages which at least work here

Comment: I added what you asked, why was the question disqualified?